# Nagios Error: The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems

Tags: centos, centos7, nagios, centos8, nagiosxi

I freshly installed Nagios on the server and post-installation I am trying to access Nagios it is giving me the error as :
**The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later**

VM: Centos 8.3

Followed this article to install Nagios: https://www.centlinux.com/2020/06/install-nagios-core-on-centos-8.html

[image]

Var logs:

Tue May 18 21:55:33.930212 2021] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 166500:tid 140296948819712] [client 10.216.80.135:62239] AH01079: **failed to make connection to backend: httpd-UDS**
[Tue May 18 21:55:34.707282 2021] [proxy:error] [pid 166500:tid 140296932034304] (2)No such file or directory: **AH02454: FCGI: attempt to connect to Unix domain socket /run/php-fpm/www.sock (*) failed**
[Tue May 18 21:55:34.707308 2021] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 166500:tid 140296932034304] [client 10.216.80.135:62240] AH01079: failed to make connection to backend: httpd-UDS
[Tue May 18 21:55:35.029155 2021] [proxy:error] [pid 166500:tid 140296574723840] (2)No such file or directory: AH02454: FCGI: attempt to connect to Unix domain socket /run/php-fpm/www.sock (*) failed
[Tue May 18 21:55:35.029183 2021] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 166500:tid 140296574723840] [client 10.216.80.135:62241] AH01079: failed to make connection to backend: httpd-UDS
[Tue May 18 21:55:38.179241 2021] [proxy:error] [pid 166500:tid 140296549545728] (2)No such file or directory: AH02454: FCGI: attempt to connect to Unix domain socket /run/php-fpm/www.sock (*) failed
[Tue May 18 21:55:38.179277 2021] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 166500:tid 140296549545728] [client 10.216.80.135:62243] AH01079: failed to make connection to backend: httpd-UDS
[Tue May 18 21:55:38.497335 2021] [proxy:error] [pid 166499:tid 140296750675712] (2)No such file or directory: AH02454: FCGI: attempt to connect to Unix domain socket /run/php-fpm/www.sock (*) failed

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo systemctl restart php-fpm
```

This doesn't look like a nagios issue specifically, it just looks like your php-fpm service isn't running. I also didn't see that command in the guide you linked, so maybe they missed it.